# Should I put a compass in carry-on or checked luggage?

Tags: airport-security

I have a compass filled with some sort of liquid. Should I put it in carry-on or checked luggage? I did not notice any warnings about it beeing flammable, but don't think it's filled with water either.

Comment: I believe you will not have issue, as there is so much liquid on that...

Comment: Compass as in "Which way is north?" or compass as in "Draw me a circle!"? I assume the first one but some of the second kind have ink reservoirs.

Comment: I don't think either of them hold 100mL or more of liquid.

Comment: The north one. Volume is not really a problem but apparently some are (used to be?) filled with kerosene. So maybe comparable to lighter.

Comment: Make sure it is kept well away from anything magnetic. A lot of electronic devices contain magnets, eg phones. Or luggage with magnetic clasps. So that could affect the compass.

Comment: The airplane's fuel tanks are full of kerosene, too. A few mL is not going to be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you have checked luggage, then put it in there. All you need is an overzealous employee to say 'aha it has liquid which *might* be kerosene, better not let it on the plane'.  Then you lose your compass.

If you have checked luggage, only take with you what you *need* onboard, and avoid the risk of having stuff confiscated :/

Answer (score 0):

This will be fine in your carry-on.
You could make extra sure and put it in a zip-lock back and present it to security checkpoints